# Win32 Clickable Right Click menu

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to make a right click menu with buttons that are clickable. I already have the code that makes a right click menu that doesn't react to anything, the code for which is below:

```cpp
HMENU hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
POINT p;
if (GetCursorPos(&p)) {
  // cursor position now in p.x and p.y
}
InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, NULL, _T("play"));
SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
TrackPopupMenu(hPopupMenu, TPM_BOTTOMALIGN | TPM_LEFTALIGN, p.x, p.y, 0, hwnd, NULL);
break;
```

Now how that I have that code above how do I give that play button an action? I have Googled around a bunch but I can't find any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the WM_COMMAND message in your application WndProc. Example:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDC_MAIN_BUTTON:
                {
                    char buffer[256];
                    SendMessage(hEdit,
                        WM_GETTEXT,
                        sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]),
                        reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(buffer));
                    MessageBox(NULL,
                        buffer,
                        "Information",
                        MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647553.aspx):

> When the user chooses a command item from a menu, the system sends a WM_COMMAND message to the window procedure. The low-order word of the WM_COMMAND message's wParam parameter contains the identifier of the chosen item. The window procedure should examine the identifier and process the message accordingly.

You didn't provide an ID for the menu item and passed `NULL`. You'll want to remedy that in case you ever need more than that one menu item.